# Задача на теорию графов

Tags: графы

Толик придумал новую технологию программирования. Он хочет уговорить друзей использовать ее. Однако все не так просто. i-й друг согласится использовать технологию Толика, если его авторитет будет не меньше ai (авторитет выражается целым числом). Как только он начнет ее использовать, к авторитету Толика прибавится число bi (попадаются люди, у которых bi < 0). Помогите Толику наставить на путь истинный как можно больше своих друзей.

Входные данные

На первой строке входного файла INPUT.TXT содержатся два числа: n (1 ≤ n ≤ 1000) – количество друзей у Толика, и первоначальный авторитет Толика . Следующие n строк содержат пары чисел ai и bi. Все числа целые, по модулю не больше 106.

Выходные данные

В выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT выведите число m - максимальное число друзей, которых может увлечь Толик, и затем m чисел - номера друзей в том порядке, в котором их нужно агитировать.

Будьте добры подкинуть идею каким вообще образом эта задача относится к графам (графы указаны в типе задачи авторами ) и/или идею решения .

Answer (score 1):

> Моё личное мнение: задача утопическая
> - так как ответ стремится к n.

**Условности решения:**

исходя из имеющихся у нас данных, после каждого разговора с приятелем будем обновлять очереди уговаривания:

- в первую очередь попадут те, у кого авторитет ниже чем у Толика, а b>0,
- во вторую очередь попадут те, у кого авторитет выше чем у Толика, а b>0,
- в третью очередь попадут те, у кого авторитет ниже чем у Толика, а b<0,
- в четвертую очередь попадут те, у кого авторитет выше чем у Толика, а b<0,
- отдельный список тех у кого b=0

*Условно: "ниже" и "меньше" включают равенство с сравниваемым значением.*

В список приглашённых будем вносить, тех кто согласились, и исключать из очередей.

Условимся также, что b - это целое число, необходимо для полной обрисовки картины второго этапа решения.

### **Решение задачи:**

**1 этап:**

Ввиду демократичности поставленной задачи (е*сли автор усложнит, то будет интереснее*), в самом начале поддаём уговорам всех людей из первой очереди, тем самым поднимая свой авторитет, мы сможем перетянуть некоторых из второй очереди в первую.

Уговариваем тех у кого b=0, добавляем их к списку успешно проагитированных. Достигнув максимума авторитета, составим список безнадёжных из остатков второй и четвёртой очередей.

**2 этап:**

Имеем: третью  очередь и списки приглашённых и безнадёжных.

Сортируем  по возрастанию модуля b.

Постепенно теряя авторитет, приглашаем первого в отсортированном списке третей очереди (исходя из принятого условия, b=(-1)). Обновляем очереди. Увеличиваем модуль b.
При равенстве b (значение уже отрицательное), предположим что таких два(Z  и Y), для простоты, получаем систему:

```
Za  ? Yb + b ? Ta

Ya  ? Za + b  ? Ta
```

В системе рассматриваются вопросы: возможно ли Толику (Ta) пригласить сначала Z  а потом Y,  или наоборот, выбираем тот вариант, при котором пригласим максимальное кол-во, то есть двух, именно эта последовательность - является ключевой. Не забываем про обновление очередей, и перестроение системы после такового.

**Этап 3**

Подготовка отчета

Подстчет успешно проагитированных, и форматирование файла согласно условию задачи.

---

Как то так.

Comment: Решение неверно . Например сейчас у Толика авторитет 10 и осталось 2 друга у которых желаемый авторитет Толика 10 и 2 соответственно и bi -6 и -2 . Вы посортируете и сагитировав второго первого сагитировать уже не сможете хотя если агитировать сначала первого то второй тоже агитируется .

Answer (score 0):

Стандартная задача на графы, все они (ну, не совсем все-все, но такие вот "олимпиадные") решаются примерно одинаково... Советую взять что-нибудь попроще для начала, чтобы "набить руку". Например - http://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/sweet-harvest

Да и вот эту можно так же решить - http://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/paths-in-the-grid - хотя в данном случае это неэффективно, там можно сообразить, как оптимизировать.

Если не заморачиваться с оптимизациями всякими, а решать "в лоб", то это несколько строк на Пайтоне получится. Но я все же надеюсь, что ты сам как-нибудь сообразишь. Если что, помогу.

Вот еще пара полезных ссылок - https://clck.ru/9Sqsr https://clck.ru/9SCaN

Comment: А, случайно, это не типичный случай задачи коммивояжера?

Comment: Я бы не сказал, что типичный...

Answer (score 0):

Итак. только что как раз решал эту задачу для N<1000 искал где бы сдать N<100000 (не нашел)
Задача либо на жадность+динамику либо на жадность.

Всех с b>=0 сортируем по возрастанию a и пытаемся взять. Очень тривиальное доказательство если можем взять i потом j при том что ai > aj можем сделать и наоборот.
Всех с b<0 сортируем по убыванию a+b (почему? аналогично прошлой строке но немного более громоздкое доказательство, попробуйте сами или прочитайте разбор)
Далее или дп (нам нужно из i первых выбрать j так что-бы сумма b была максимальной) dp[i][j] = max(dp[i-1][j], если авторитет после положительных + dp[i-1][j-1] >= a[i] учесть dp[i-1][j-1]+b[i]) а потом восстановление пути получим самих друзей
Или жадность: нам выгодно брать всех подряд и отменять человека с самым маленьким b в том случае если это приведет к тому что мы сможем взять текущего с большим b (к-во то же авторитет не измениться).
Мой код на java http://ideone.com/kpAqgc

```
private Friend[] friends;
private int authority;
private Main(int authority, int a[], int b[]) {
    this.authority = authority;
    friends = new Friend[a.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < friends.length; ++i) {
        friends[i] = new Friend(a[i], b[i], i+1);
    }
}

Comparator < Friend > sortCompare = new Comparator<Friend>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Friend o1, Friend o2) {
        return o2.a+o2.b-o1.a-o1.b;
    }
};

private Friend[] solveNegativeDp(Friend[] negative) {
    Arrays.sort(negative, sortCompare);

    Integer[][] maxBSum = new Integer[negative.length+1][negative.length+1];
    maxBSum[0][0] = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= negative.length; ++i) {
        maxBSum[i][0] = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j <= negative.length; ++j) {
            if (maxBSum[i-1][j-1] != null && authority + maxBSum[i-1][j-1] >= negative[i-1].a) {
                maxBSum[i][j] = maxBSum[i-1][j-1] + negative[i-1].b;
            }
            if (maxBSum[i][j] == null || maxBSum[i-1][j] != null && maxBSum[i-1][j] >= maxBSum[i][j]) {
                maxBSum[i][j] = maxBSum[i-1][j];
            }
        }
    }

    int j, i = negative.length;
    for (j = negative.length; maxBSum[i][j] == null; --j);

    Friend[] negativeAdded = new Friend[j];
    for (; i >= 0 && j > 0; --i) {
        if (maxBSum[i][j] != maxBSum[i-1][j]) {
            negativeAdded[--j] = negative[i-1];
        }
    }

    return negativeAdded;
}

private Friend[] solveNegativeGreedy(Friend[] negative) {
    Arrays.sort(negative, sortCompare);        

    PriorityQueue<Friend> negativeAdded = new PriorityQueue<>(1, new Comparator<Friend>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Friend o1, Friend o2) {
            return o1.b - o2.b;
        }
    });        
    for (Friend friend : negative) {
        if (authority >= friend.a) {
            authority += friend.b;
            negativeAdded.add(friend);
        } else if (!negativeAdded.isEmpty() && authority - negativeAdded.peek().b >= friend.a && negativeAdded.peek().b < friend.b) {
            authority = authority - negativeAdded.poll().b + friend.b;
            negativeAdded.add(friend);
        }
    }

    Friend[] answer = negativeAdded.toArray(new Friend[negativeAdded.size()]);
    Arrays.sort(answer, sortCompare);
    return answer;
}

private Friend[] convinceMaxFriends(){
    Vector < Friend > convinced = new Vector<>();
    Vector < Friend > positive = new Vector<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < friends.length; ++i) {
        if (friends[i].b >= 0) {
            positive.add(friends[i]);
        }
    }

    positive.sort(new Comparator<Friend>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Friend o1, Friend o2) {
            return o1.a - o2.a;
        }
    });

    for (Friend friend : positive) {
        if (authority >= friend.a) {
            authority += friend.b;
            convinced.add(friend);
        }
    }

    Friend[] negative = new Friend[friends.length - positive.size()];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < friends.length; ++i) {
        if (friends[i].b < 0) {
            negative[j++] = friends[i];
        }
    }


    convinced.addAll(Arrays.asList(solveNegativeGreedy(negative)));

    return convinced.toArray(new Friend[convinced.size()]);
}

private class Friend {
    private int a, b, index;
    private Friend(int a, int b, int index) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.index = index;
    }
}
```

Сдать можно тут http://acmp.ru/?main=task&id_task=572
Немного другой разбор можно попытаться найти в дне Копелиовича в Харьковской Школе 2013